# Is there a Gmail notifier that works with multiple accounts?

Tags: 11.04, unity, 11.10, unity-2d, gmail

Is there something equivalent to `gnome-gmail-notifier` for Unity and Unity 2D on Ubuntu 11.04/11.10?

'equivalent' means that it must notify about new emails from multiple normal GMail and Google Apps GMail accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, self answering my question.

`gnome-gmail-notifier` works on Unity and Unity 2D too if you follow these steps:

1. type in Terminal:
   `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`
2. log out
3. log in

*Edit:*

if you are using **Unity 2D** [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/847525) makes `'all'` not working. A patch has been approved for Oneiric but not released yet.
Workaround:
`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['Gnome-gmail-notifier']"`
(Capital `G` is needed.)

Comment: Note that you probably shouldn't just give your password to any software that asks for it.

Comment: @mlissner Gmail allows application-specific passwords for this reason.

Answer (score 10):

You can install the package [gm-notify](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gm-notify) [[Install gm-notify](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gm-notify)]

Otherwise, open up the Software Center (on the launcher), then do a search for "gm-notify". Once you've found it, mark it for installation, then go click "Install". Once that's done, you can launch it from the Applications lens by typing in "Gmail" and selecting it. Once it's launched, you can then configure it.

Comment: Upvoted but not accepted because `gm-notify` handles only one account at the time. Moreover I did not find any way to change the account settings once they have been configured. I have found a simple way to make `gnome-gmail-notifier` working on Unity too (see my answer).

Comment: Ok, found the way to reconfigure `gm-notify`: open Application lens (`Super-A`), type `gmail` and choose `GMail Notifier Configuration`.

Comment: Related: [Support multiple accounts (Bug #373231)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gm-notify/+bug/373231)

Answer (score 2):

### Popper E-mail Notifier

Popper reads the new emails from POP3 and IMAP email servers and notifies about the number, subject, sender and time of new emails in the indicator applet and via a notification bubble.

You can read more here

https://launchpad.net/popper integrates nicely as indicator for any email provider

Answer (score 1):

I believe Cloud Services Notifications is the best app for what you're looking for. It works in either systray or indicator mode and checks Gmail, Google Reader, POP3, etc.

https://launchpad.net/cloudsn